# Setting up tty autologin on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, tty, autologin

I was trying to setup tty auto login for FreeBSD, I copied the `P|Pc|Pc` part and made a change:

```
Pcal console:\
  :al=root:ht:np:sp#9600
```

And modify the tty for ttyv0:

`ttyv0 "/usr/libexec/getty Pcal" xterm on secure`

But now if I do `init q`, I get:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing:

```
Pcal|Pcal console:\ 
        :al=root:ht:np:sp#9600

ttyv0 "/usr/libexec/getty Pcal" xterm on secure
```

Now Pcal will be the gettytab entry. `|` is used as a separator. This to enter alternative names (not sure about that I'm not a gettytab expert ;) ). The last entry until `:\` looks like  a "human readable" string for the gettytab line.

See if this works. Does anyone know where the `|` is used for? And how you should read those gettytab entries?

Comment: The `|` worked, althrough I don't understand why